# Quartz instance should only run specific jobs, not all

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz in a clustered environment with multiple JBoss AS. There a several applications that are using Quartz. Currently, application a will store its jobs in tables with the A_QURTZ_ prefix, application B B_QURTZ_ and so on.

So the Quartz configuration is nearly identical except for

```
<prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">A_QRTZ_</prop>
<prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">B_QRTZ_</prop>
...
```

Is it possible to use the same tablePrefix for different applications and distinguish the jobs by their group so that Quartz schedulers from application A are only running their jobs and none from application B?

Comment: That's unusual.... why not using different scheduler names?

Comment: You mean something like

    <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">Application_A_Scheduler</prop>
and
    <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">Application_B_Scheduler</prop>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn, you're right, Leo. It's much easier than I thought.

Using different

```
<prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">Application_A_Scheduler</prop>
```

settings is working fine. Jobs created by Application_A_Scheduler are automatically only executed by Application_A_Scheduler instances, not by Application_B_Scheduler instances.